# org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not write to file ...\build\poms\pom-default.xml

Tags: gradle, snapshot, sonatype

Hi I am getting this error and i could not figure out what the problem is, as it was working before. This will happen when i try to upload snapshot jars to SonaType snapshots repository.

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':framework:uploadProguardArchives'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.PublishException: Could not publish configuration 'proguardArchives'
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.upload(Upload.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not write to file 'D:\git\RoboBinding\framework\build\poms\pom-default.xml'.
    at org.gradle.internal.IoActions$TextFileWriterIoAction.execute(IoActions.java:115)
    at org.gradle.internal.IoActions$TextFileWriterIoAction.execute(IoActions.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.IoActions.writeTextFile(IoActions.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.DefaultMavenPom.writeTo(DefaultMavenPom.java:197)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.DefaultMavenPom.writeTo(DefaultMavenPom.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.DefaultArtifactPom.writePom(DefaultArtifactPom.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.DefaultArtifactPomContainer.createDeployableFilesInfos(DefaultArtifactPomContainer.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.AbstractMavenResolver.publish(AbstractMavenResolver.java:96)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.AbstractMavenResolver.publish(AbstractMavenResolver.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyDependencyPublisher.publish(DefaultIvyDependencyPublisher.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyBackedArtifactPublisher$1.execute(IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyBackedArtifactPublisher$1.execute(IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$3.transform(Transformers.java:131)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.publish(IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.upload(Upload.java:64)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at build_14oq31t5ii5c4emkiummgdb7it$_run_closure17_closure33_closure34_closure38.doCall(D:\git\RoboBinding\framework\build.gradle:309)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.xml.XmlTransformer$XmlProviderImpl.apply(XmlTransformer.java:165)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.xml.XmlTransformer.doTransform(XmlTransformer.java:137)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.xml.XmlTransformer.doTransform(XmlTransformer.java:125)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.xml.XmlTransformer.transform(XmlTransformer.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.DefaultMavenPom.writeNonEffectivePom(DefaultMavenPom.java:207)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.DefaultMavenPom.writeTo(DefaultMavenPom.java:189)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.DefaultMavenPom$1.execute(DefaultMavenPom.java:199)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.DefaultMavenPom$1.execute(DefaultMavenPom.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.IoActions$TextFileWriterIoAction.execute(IoActions.java:110)
    ... 71 more
```

This is My [build.gradle](https://github.com/RoboBinding/RoboBinding/blob/develop/framework/build.gradle) and the task i run is as follows:

```
gradlew framework:uploadProguardArchives -PrepositoryUserName=xxx -PrepositoryPassword=xxx
```

Thanks in advance!

Cheng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely a bug in the build script. `D:\git\RoboBinding\framework\build.gradle:309` throws a NPE.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Good spot. Groovy confuses me a bit.